# Azure TLS certificate changes

Tags: azure

We have received the below email from Microsoft. The certificates my IIS apps are using were issued by ssl2buy.  I will be impacted or not. Maybe, you can help me.

"We are updating Azure services in a phased manner to use Transport Layer Security (TLS) certificates from a different set of Root Certificate Authorities (CAs). This began 13 August 2020.

Your applications may be impacted if you explicitly specify a list of acceptable CAs (a practice known as certificate pinning)."

Comment: If you enable other companies / people to integrate with your site, then they will be impacted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace your root and intermediate certificates by reissuing your current certificate. You can download your root and intermediate certificates as per your purchased certificate.

Comodo certificate:
https://sectigo.com/resource-library/sectigo-root-intermediate-certificate-files

AlphaSSL certificate:
https://support.globalsign.com/ca-certificates/root-certificates/trusted-root-intermediate-certificates

DigiCert / GeoTrust / RapidSSL / Thawte certificate:
https://www.digicert.com/kb/digicert-root-certificates.htm

I would suggest you to share the product name and the certificate authority name which you have purchased and the names of the files which you have received or downloaded so that we can help you with the installation process.

You can also [contact our security experts](https://www.ssl2buy.com/contact-us) via live chat or support ticket, they will assist you and give right solutions instantly.